# Mi props con vue.js me pasa el valor como indefinido

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy utilizando vue.js para hacer una consulta con un valor desde una vista pero al momento de pasar el valor del props me manda la impresión de la consola como **"undefined"** debido a eso no puedo hacer ninguna consulta por el valor indefinido que envía este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
import ApiCanal10 from '../lib/api-canal10'

export default {
  props: ['idVideo'],
  data: () => ({
    videos: []
  }),
  created() {
    //do something after creating vue instance
    this.api = new ApiCanal10({})
    this.getRelVideos()

  },
  methods: {
    getRelVideos: function() {
      //este es lo que se envia la consola
      console.log(`video/related/${this.idVideo}`)
    }
  }
}
```

debido al indefinido no se puedo hacer las consulta que se necesitan para mostrar la información.

Answer (score 0):

Hice una prueba rápida con varios elementos de tu código y me funciona sin problema, ¿tal vez estás definiendo mal el parámetro cuando llamas al componente? Ten en cuenta la sintaxis camel-case como funciona: `<child id-video="hola amigos!"></child>`

```js
Vue.component('child', {

  props: ['idVideo'],
  template: '<span>{{ idVideo }}</span>',
  created() {
    this.getRelVideos()
  },
  methods: {
    getRelVideos() {
      //este es lo que se envia la consola
      console.log(`video/related/${this.idVideo}`)
    }
  }
  
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child id-video="hola amigos!"></child>
</div>
```